# install4j gives error _CTFontCopyDefaultCascadeListForLanguages

Tags: macos, osx-lion, install4j

Some users with Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) are getting this error when they try to install our product, which is made with Install4j v6.1 and Java 8u162 is bundled with it. It works fine on *High Sierra* and *El Capitan* (we only have those two for testing).

Google doesn't find anything about `_CTFontCopyDefaultCascadeListForLanguages` and I wouldn't know how I could help the users other than giving them our *.tar.gz alternative. Maybe install4j 7 has this fixed?

Some users with 10.13.3 seem to have similar problems.

```
Process:         java [1345]
Path:            /usr/bin/java
Identifier:      net.java.openjdk.cmd
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  JavaApplicationStub [1326]

Date/Time:       2018-04-01 08:40:23.614 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          1764779 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           380
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  8 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      30BEE59A-23E1-4996-A873-8C05A3B43477

Crashed Thread:  28  Java: AWT-EventQueue-0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[1345]: garbage collection is OFF

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _CTFontCopyDefaultCascadeListForLanguages
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/*/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libawt_lwawt.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error on OS X 10.7.5. It occurred after I updated my java version and prevented me from opening certain applications on my machine. I had to **revert to Java version 8u161** to get back up and running.

Download the installer file, `jre-8u161-macosx-x64.dmg`, from the Oracle archive:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html

First you may need to uninstall the existing version of java, or the installer may fail:

```
# Uninstall Java
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Java
```

Notes on uninstalling Java: https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

Comment: Yes, it seems they dropped support for older OS X versions but didn't update all the documents. There's an FAQ which claims that Java 8 runs on OS X 10.7.5, but that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

> Referenced from: /private/var/folders/*/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libawt_lwawt.dylib

This seems to be a Java problem rather than install4j problem. Do you get the same error if you start the application from the command line with the `java` launcher?

Comment: But Java is bundled and it's the latest version. I don't get the problem at all. Only some users and most of them have OS X 10.7.5. And it's the installer, which contains java but isn't started using java from the command line.

Comment: 10.7 is very old, maybe the recent Java releases are not tested on that version.

Comment: 10.7.3 should support latest Java according to Oracle. I'll report this to Oracle.

Comment: Done. Bug-ID: 9053306